# dynamically generated ID's needs to be radio buttons name as attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons groups containing three options each and i have added group id's dynamically.

What i wanted is: for each group - radio name must match with its relevant group id name

- `group1` contains three radio buttons with name attribute `group1`
- `group2` contains three radio buttons with name attribute `group2`

```js
//this script is used to add groupid's
$('.wraper').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id', "group" + (i + 1));
});
```

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=radio]+div {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="checkedClass tabboxfor" for="a">a</label>
    <label class="tabboxfor" for="b">b</label>
    <label class="tabboxfor" for="c">c</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="radio" id="a" class="" checked="checked" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="b" class="" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="c" class="" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>c</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="wraper">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="checkedClass tabboxfor" for="x">x</label>
    <label class="tabboxfor" for="y">y</label>
    <label class="tabboxfor" for="z">z</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="radio" id="x" class="" checked="checked" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>xxx</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="y" class="" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>yyy</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="z" class="" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>zzz</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please edit the code to see, for the time being i have added hardcoded values like: (name="group1") and (name="group2")

Comment: So you want ID for wrapper and name for radio to be generated

Comment: So... What is your question ?

Comment: @Satpal, yes you got it, i have added groupid's using script. now i want for radio's to be the same name

Comment: I have edited question so that its not misleading and removed `id` and `name` attribute from radio, as these needs to be generated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to target [`:radio`](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) element to set `.attr()`

```
$('.wraper').each(function(i) {
    var groupId = "group" + (i + 1);
    $(this).attr('id', groupId );
    $(this).find(':radio').attr('name', groupId);
});
```

```js
//this script is used to add groupid's
$('.wraper').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id', "group" + (i + 1));
  $(this).find(':radio').attr('name', this.id)
});
```

```css
input[type=radio],
input[type=radio]+div {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wraper" id="group1">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="checkedClass tabboxfor" for="a">a</label>
    <label class="tabboxfor" for="b">b</label>
    <label class="tabboxfor" for="c">c</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="radio" id="a" class="" checked="checked" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="b" class="" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>a</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="c" class="" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>c</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="wraper" id="group2">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="checkedClass tabboxfor" for="x">x</label>
    <label class="tabboxfor" for="y">y</label>
    <label class="tabboxfor" for="z">z</label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="radio" id="x" class="" checked="checked" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>xxx</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="y" class="" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>yyy</p>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" id="z" class="" />
    <div class="box">
      <p>zzz</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you mean this - you want inputs inside wrapper to follow naming rules.Correct?

```
$('.wraper').each(function(i) {
    var groupId = "group" + (i + 1);

    $(this).attr('id', groupId );
    $(this).find('input').attr('name', groupId );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct this is what you are expecting :

```
$('.wraper').each(function(i) { 
   $(this).attr('id', "group" + (i + 1));
     $(this).children("input"). each (function (){
       $(this).attr("name","group" + (I+1));
     });
 });
```